# Class extends classA, but has parent of classB... how?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, joomla

Edit: Please disregard this quesion. This was a goof on my end: I was looking at one class (OpicControllerInsurance) and assuming it was another (OpicControllerInsurances).  The only thing you have to learn from this question is that you need to doublecheck your input/output *even when you think it's beyond question*.

I have a class that inherits from JControllerAdmin (it's a joomla project, but it doesn't look like a joomla-specific problem):

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.controlleradmin');

/**
 * Insurance Type list controller class.
 *
 * @package     Joomla.Administrator
 * @subpackage  com_opic
 * @since       1.6
 */
class OpicControllerInsurances extends JControllerAdmin
{
...
```

And here's where an instance of the class is being created

```
// Instantiate the class.
   if (class_exists($class)) {
      // $class == 'OpicControllerInsurance', $config == ''
      $instance = new $class($config);         

      $test_class_name = get_class($instance); 
      // $test_class_name == OpicControllerInsurance

      $test_parent_class_name = get_parent_class($instance); 
      // $test_parent_class_name == JControllerForm
   }
```

Now, if OpicControllerInsurances extends JControllerAdmin how is it possible that it's parent class is JControllerForm??  This is one of those frustrating problems that seems to defy basic programming rules (which generally means that I simply don't understand the rules very well).

Comment: Hmm.. I would be confused too. I don't see any reason this would happen, JControllerAdmin and JControllerForm both inherit from JController... Is JControllerForm referenced anywhere in your project? You could try posting more relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm.

Of course; oop doesn't work that way.  I was caught up by the Joomla MVC which has singular and plural names for each model (at least in this configuration).  I didn't spot the difference between OpicControllerInsurances and OpicControllerInsurance in the debugger.

Comment: Yikes.  That's a bad naming practice.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be unusual for MVC implementations though.  In this case I'm borrowing all the naming from one of the core components in Joomla.